# how do i parse json value and get id into variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

hello i am having this code of jquery:

```
var fbuid = zuck;
var fbjson = $.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/"+fbuid);
```

how to get the id from json directly into var :

```
{
id: "4",
first_name: "Mark",
gender: "male",
last_name: "Zuckerberg",
link: "https://www.facebook.com/zuck",
locale: "en_US",
name: "Mark Zuckerberg",
username: "zuck"
}
```

all i would like to get id from json to var as below:

```
var fbjson.id;
```

how i do it using jquery?

Comment: should really start by reading the API docs for `$.getJSON`. They even include examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're close but you've got some things you need to adjust. Ajax is async which means that you're waiting on a server response. You need to fill your data once you have that piece of data. Note you will not be able to reference fbjson until AFTER the getJSON has fired and completed.

According to the [jQuery documentation for getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

you need to have a callback similar to this -

```
var fbuid = 'zuck';
var fbjson;

$.getJSON( "https://graph.facebook.com/"+fbuid, function( data ) {
  fbjson = data;
});
```

Notice I assign the fbjson in the callback to data which is the server response. now you can reference it as

```
fbjson.id
```

Comment: But fbjson is only a string at first. I think you should call some parse command in order to get a real object (?). `fbjson = JSON.parse(data);`or so.

Comment: If it's being returned with a json header it's not a string and you are free to access as json.